# facebook login using zend_auth_adapter in Zend Framework

Tags: facebook, zend-framework

Can anyone tell me how to implement facebook App login in Zend framework. I done it in Zend Framework using normal PHP but it contain lots of problem and hard code. My code contain Zend_Auth_Adapter for authentication in which I check my database authentication for correct username and password. I want to make same this for facebook login. I refer lots of tutorials but that does'nt working. How to implements this? Give me step by step solution because I am new in Zend Framework. Or give any link that provide step by step solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: How about this: https://github.com/erickthered/Facebook-PHP-SDK-for-Zend-Framework

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really simple. You'll need to use the Facebook sdk: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.

The basic code should read something like:

```
$fb = new Facebook($config);
if($this->_getParam('code')) {

  if($token = $fb->getAccessToken()) {

    //Do your own logic, but log them in:

    $result = new Zend_Auth_Result(Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS, $user->id);
    Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($result->getIdentity());

  } else
    //Clear identity

} else
  //redirect using $fb->getLoginUrl()
```